# What happened during this shuttle simulation malfunction involving a failure of a shuttle arm joint while moving the JEF?

Tags: iss, space-shuttle, failure, simulation, training

[This author](https://spaceflight.training/big_mal.htm) (*cough*) begins to relate the details of a particular training incident during simulations for STS-127. However, they very sadly have not finished the tale. Does anybody (*cough cough*) know what happened?

Comment: The link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @DrSheldon it has some pretty strict geo-blocking. Or, sometimes reloading it works.

Comment: That got ported over from an old blog and...yeah, I should finish it sometime.

Comment: You know where to notify your rabid readers when you do :)

Comment: Okay, reloading the link worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr It went as planned except that vetting of the revised ISS robotics procedure took longer than expected, causing some friction internal to the training team.

The setting is an [STS-127](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-127) joint integrated simulation. The planned malfunction was a one-way jam of the shuttle arm's shoulder yaw joint as it moved the Japanese Exposed Facility (JEF) towards a handoff to the station arm.

For details, please refer to the timeline shown here:

[image]

> At the top is Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) and Mission Elapsed Time
>   (MET). ...  The fat gray bar at the bottom is
>   the crew schedule and shows Houston time just above it.
>
> The first vertical red line is the sim start time. Houston time it's 8
>   am Tuesday, April 21, 2009. The simulation start point is GMT July 18,
>   2009 just after 13:00 hours, which corresponds to MET 2/15:00:00 (2
>   days, fifteen hours after launch). ...
>   The last vertical red line is the end of the sim, 27 hours later....
>
> I have highlighted the robotics activities in yellow.

- Timeline point A: Insertion of the malfunction while the shuttle arm was moving the payload to the second handoff position.

> The malfunction worked beautifully. There were no alarms or
>   annunciations - I had chosen a point at which the payload was moving
>   quite parallel to the payload bay sill and the primary joint driving
>   was the one I broke. So the payload's trajectory did not diverge from
>   the projected one enough to cause a ... alarm. The crew noticed that
>   motion had stopped, and about that time, the ground called to have
>   them take the brakes on.

- Timeline point B: After troubleshooting, STS and ISS robotics teams have converged on a revised handoff position.

[image]

> However, after this point, things went a little sour. Even though the
>   new handoff position was determined, it took longer than we had
>   expected for the ISS team to prepare, test, and doublecheck their
>   procedure revisions. The training leads started to get antsy. To be
>   fair, we had committed to them that we could still get the JEF
>   installed before the crew went to sleep on FD4, but it was looking
>   increasingly unlikely that it was going to happen by then. The
>   training leads started talking about "King's Xing" the mal - meaning
>   that we would take it out and pretend like it never happened. I was
>   not a fan of this plan at all because it would leave the planning
>   shift with nothing to work on. There were some "frank exchanges of
>   views" both on the airwaves and over the loops. Finally it was decided
>   that the STL would ask ISS Flight [Holly Ridings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holly_Ridings) what she thought about
>   the situation. To my everlasting gratitude, ISS Flight said
>   (paraphrasing) that she liked the case and preferred that we let the
>   teams work through it. The JEF would be placed in a pre-install
>   position and left there overnight, the install would be done on FD5.

- Timeline point C: The shuttle arm moved the JEF to the new handoff position.
- Timeline point D: The station arm grapples the JEF.
- Timeline point E: The station arm has moved the JEF to the pre-install position.  Everyone except the planning shift went home for the night.
- Timeline point F: The JEF has been berthed by the station arm.
- Timeline point G: The attachment mechanism has completed its process of coupling the JEF to the JEM-PM. The station arm has ungrappled.

> To sum up, I relearned once again that it would not be the technical
>   things that bit me, but the human and administrative ones.

Acronymology:

- FD **F**light **D**ay
- JEM-PM **J**apanese **E**xperiment **M**odule - **P**ressurized **M**odule
- STL **S**tation **T**raining **L**ead

Overly long and detailed reference [here](https://spaceflight.training/big_mal_finale.htm).